# opening file from mail in Unity3d app and handling the file

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wish to create my own file type to use in my app. I have already [linked a file type to my app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html) but now i need to tell the app to handle the file, so when i open a file that i sent over email, i open it with my app.

This is where i didn't figure it out yet.

How can i handle the file that i sent via email in unity3d code?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the property "Application supports iTunes file sharing" to true in Xcode -> Info -> Custom iOS Target Properties, you will see that the file you've opened with your app is visible in itunes -> your_device -> Apps -> File Sharing in a folder named "Inbox".

So, what unity3d does, it makes a copy of the file you've opened with your app and stores it in your Documents folder for your app under the Inbox folder. Hope this is useful.

Also, you can implement this in native code (iOS) from here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

Comment: is there a similar routine for Android ?